# Core Plot - Bar plot automatic initial zooming

Tags: ios, core-plot

How do I set an initial zoom based the maximum value of the x-axis and y-axis?

Example:

Plot 1:

Maximum value:
x-axis = 100;
y-axis = 110;

Plot 2:

Maximum value:
x-axis = 180;
y-axis = 230;

I need to the initial zoom be equal to two plots.

Regards

Comment: Are the plots in the same plot space?

Comment: Yes, I use one plot space on one view controller to show three differents Bar  plot types

Answer (score 1):

This will adjust the plot space to fit the plot data for two plots:

```
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:@[plot1, plot2]];
```

You can use this shortcut to scale the plot space to fit all of the plots in a graph:

```
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];
```